# Convert OR to Union in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, lambda

OR clause in the LINQ query is causing performance issue. If I change it to Union performance improves a lot. Here is current query. How do I convert `(includeBatch && i.BatchId != null || includeSingle && i.BatchId == null)` this part of query to Union.

Original Call:

```
var inputs = _inputRepository.GetProcessorQueue(includeBatch, includeSingle, companyIds);
```

Current Solution: Making two calls and doing union operation

```
if (includeSingle && includeBatch)
{
var inputsSingle = _inputRepository.GetProcessorQueue(false, includeSingle, companyIds);
var inputsBatch = _inputRepository.GetProcessorQueue(includeBatch, false, companyIds);  

return inputsSingle.Union(inputsBatch).ToList();
}
else
{
var inputs = _inputRepository.GetProcessorQueue(includeBatch, includeSingle, companyIds);
return inputs.Select(Input.ToQueueInputExpression(inputQueueMetaDataTypes)).ToList();
}
```

Original LINQ:

```
public IQueryable<Input> GetProcessorQueue(bool includeBatch, bool includeSingle, int[] companyIds)
        {
            return FindAsQueryableReadOnly(i => !i.IsDeleted
                && i.InputTypeId == (int)InputType.Values.TRANSPORTATION
                && i.ExportedStatusId != (int)ExportedStatus.Values.EXPORTED
                && ImportStatus.DataEntryQueue.Contains(i.ImportStatusId) 
                && ((i.TransportationInput.TransportationInputTypeId == (int)TransportationInputType.Values.FACTOR
                        && (includeBatch && i.BatchId != null || includeSingle && i.BatchId == null)
                        && !i.DocumentOnlyStatus)
                    || (includeBatch && i.BatchId != null && i.DocumentOnlyStatus && i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentId != null)
                )
                && (companyIds == null || !companyIds.Any() || companyIds.Contains(i.CompanyId)),
                i => i.Batch,
                i => i.ImportStatus,
                i => i.InputCharges,
                i => i.InputDocumentStats,
                i => i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin,
                i => i.InputDocumentStats.Document.DocumentMetaData);
        }
```

Original SQL: (removed select statement for readability)

```
FROM [eroom].[Input] AS [i]
INNER JOIN [eroom].[ImportStatus] AS [i.ImportStatus] ON [i].[ImportStatusId] = [i.ImportStatus].[ImportStatusId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[Batch] AS [i.Batch] ON [i].[BatchId] = [i.Batch].[BatchId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[InputDocumentStats] AS [i.InputDocumentStats] ON [i].[InputId] = [i.InputDocumentStats].[InputId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[DocumentOrigin] AS [i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin] ON [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentOriginId] = [i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin].[DocumentOriginId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[Document] AS [i.InputDocumentStats.Document] ON [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentId] = [i.InputDocumentStats.Document].[DocumentId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[TransportationInput] AS [i.TransportationInput] ON [i].[InputId] = [i.TransportationInput].[InputId]
WHERE ((((([i].[HiddenStatus] = 0) AND ([i].[InputTypeId] = 1)) AND ([i].[ExportedStatusId] <> 3)) AND [i].[ImportStatusId] IN (1, 4, 5, 7)) AND (((([i.TransportationInput].[TransportationInputTypeId] = 1) AND ([i].[BatchId] IS NOT NULL OR [i].[BatchId] IS NULL)) AND ([i].[DocumentOnlyStatus] = 0)) OR (([i].[BatchId] IS NOT NULL AND ([i].[DocumentOnlyStatus] = 1)) AND [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentId] IS NOT NULL))) AND [i].[CompanyId] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Better performance SQL (removed select statement for readability)

```
FROM [eroom].[Input] AS [i]
INNER JOIN [eroom].[ImportStatus] AS [i.ImportStatus] ON [i].[ImportStatusId] = [i.ImportStatus].[ImportStatusId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[Batch] AS [i.Batch] ON [i].[BatchId] = [i.Batch].[BatchId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[InputDocumentStats] AS [i.InputDocumentStats] ON [i].[InputId] = [i.InputDocumentStats].[InputId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[DocumentOrigin] AS [i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin] ON [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentOriginId] = [i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin].[DocumentOriginId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[Document] AS [i.InputDocumentStats.Document] ON [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentId] = [i.InputDocumentStats.Document].[DocumentId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[TransportationInput] AS [i.TransportationInput] ON [i].[InputId] = [i.TransportationInput].[InputId]
WHERE ((((([i].[HiddenStatus] = 0) AND ([i].[InputTypeId] = 1)) AND ([i].[ExportedStatusId] <> 3)) AND [i].[ImportStatusId] IN (1, 4, 5, 7)) AND (((([i.TransportationInput].[TransportationInputTypeId] = 1) AND [i].[BatchId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([i].[DocumentOnlyStatus] = 0)) OR (([i].[BatchId] IS NOT NULL AND ([i].[DocumentOnlyStatus] = 1)) AND [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentId] IS NOT NULL))) AND [i].[CompanyId] IN (1, 2, 3)


UNION

FROM [eroom].[Input] AS [i]
INNER JOIN [eroom].[ImportStatus] AS [i.ImportStatus] ON [i].[ImportStatusId] = [i.ImportStatus].[ImportStatusId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[Batch] AS [i.Batch] ON [i].[BatchId] = [i.Batch].[BatchId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[InputDocumentStats] AS [i.InputDocumentStats] ON [i].[InputId] = [i.InputDocumentStats].[InputId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[DocumentOrigin] AS [i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin] ON [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentOriginId] = [i.InputDocumentStats.DocumentOrigin].[DocumentOriginId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[Document] AS [i.InputDocumentStats.Document] ON [i.InputDocumentStats].[DocumentId] = [i.InputDocumentStats.Document].[DocumentId]
LEFT JOIN [eroom].[TransportationInput] AS [i.TransportationInput] ON [i].[InputId] = [i.TransportationInput].[InputId]
WHERE ((((([i].[HiddenStatus] = 0) AND ([i].[InputTypeId] = 1)) AND ([i].[ExportedStatusId] <> 3)) AND [i].[ImportStatusId] IN (1, 4, 5, 7)) AND ((([i.TransportationInput].[TransportationInputTypeId] = 1) AND [i].[BatchId] IS NULL) AND ([i].[DocumentOnlyStatus] = 0))) AND [i].[CompanyId] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

```
 public IQueryable<T> FindAsQueryableReadOnly(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet.AsQueryable();
            query = IncludeProperties(includeProperties, query);
            return query.Where(where).AsNoTracking();
        }
```

Comment: Why not just make 1 call to a stored procedure?

Comment: Its not allowed in this company.

Comment: Is this line `inputsSingle.Union(inputsBatch).ToList();` not returning a select with union?

Comment: It throws an error..Here is the method it calls FindAsQueryableReadOnly

Comment: Error: The input sequence must have items of type 'TBC.ERoom.Models.Input', but it has items of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject'.
Parameter name: inputInfo

Comment: Please update your question with the new details. Please add what is wrong with the current solution. Also, where does the error occur?

Comment: You should've said that earlier. It's hard for me to spot where the error is but you can try to use your `dbcontext.Inputs` directly intead of `FindAsQueryableReadOnly` to query and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It throws error at this line `return inputsSingle.Union(inputsBatch).ToList();` when trying to convert it to list

Comment: @Luci Does your query works at all or you only get this error when using `union`? Please edit your question so we can know **exactly** what is your problem.